# How to get an Ecore feature disply name without an object instance?

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'd like to create a GUI table to display a given list of features of an `EObject` sub-class. To do this I have to get the display names of the features for the column header.

How do I get the feature display names in the best way?

### One solution that seems a bit like a hack:

If I have an instance of the class then I can use the adaptor factory to get a `IItemPropertySource` that can do this:

```java
SomeEntity e = ...
String displayName = adaptorFactory.adapt(e, IItemPropertySource.class)
    .getPropertyDescriptor(null, feature).getDisplayName(null));
```

But when the table is empty there is no `SomeEntity` object handy to use to get the `IItemPropertySource`.

I can create a dummy object using the `EFactory` in this way:

```java
EClass containingClass = feature.getEContainingClass();
SomeEntity dummy = containingClass.getEPackage().getEFactoryInstance()
    .create(containingClass));
```

... and then use that object the get the `IItemPropertySource`. But this seem a bit like a hack. Is there no better solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the class at compile time, you can create the `ItemProviderAdapter` yourself:

```java
MyClassItemProvider provider = new MyClassItemProvider(adaptorFactory);
String name = provider.getPropertyDescriptor(null, property).getDisplayName(null);
```

If you do not know the class at compile time, but only have an `EClass` instance at runtime, things are more complicated, because the necessary methods are protected. You have to "make" them public first.

I would add respective methods to the generated `MyPackageSwitch` and `MyPackageAdapterFactory` classes (in myPackage.util).

In `MyPackageAdapterFactory`:

```java
/**
 * @generated NOT
 */
public MyPackageSwitch<Adapter> getModelSwitch() {
    return modelSwitch;
}
```

In `MyPackageSwitch`:

```java
/**
 * generated NOT
 */
public T doPublicSwitch(EClass theEClass, EObject theEObject) {
    return doSwitch(theEClass, theEObject);
}
```

Now you can create an `ItemProviderAdapter` for an `EClass` `theEClass` like this:

```java
provider = (ItemProviderAdapter) adapterFactory.getModelSwitch()
        .doPublicSwitch(theEClass, null);
```

EMF was obviously not made for this. Keep in mind that this all is only working if you do not have any custom provider implementations that uses the `EObject` values.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I didn't know that there is a generated model switch, that might come in handy sometime.

Comment: One additional problem is that my model is divided into three separate projects with separate model files and separate adapter factories. I want to write code that works generically with any of these sub-models. Your solution maybe can be adopted to do this with some custom code, but that's an extra hassle.

Comment: All things considered I think I prefer the solution to create a dummy object and use `adaptorFactory.adapt(dummy, IItemPropertySource.class)`. (`adaptorFactory` here is a composed adapter factory containing all relevant specific factories.)

Comment: Yes of course, you always can just create an empty instance of an EClass and use that.